# Compare MySQL data with another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This code below echoes out 8 names from `tableOne`, but I want to compare those names with 8 names in another table. I want to compare the rows echoed in `$row['weight']` with `tableTwo`, and if the results don't match, then add a `<span class="strike"> </span>` to the result echoed in `$row['weight']`.

How do I go about adding an if/else to `$row['weight']` compare each name with the names in another table?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableOne LIMIT 0, 8");

$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo $i. " - " . $row['weight'] . '<br>';
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some simple code to get you started:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableOne LIMIT 0, 8");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableTwo LIMIT 0, 8");

$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $value1 = $row['weight'];
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $value2 = $row2['weight'];
    echo $i . " - table 1: ";
    echo $value1;
    echo ", table 2: - ";
    if ($value2 != $value1) {
        echo '<span class="strike">$value2</span>';
    } else {
        echo $value2;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

You can make the code smarter, to handle cases where there aren't 8 values to compare, and to display the values in an HTML table too, but hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: Thanks, should it be `$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);` instead of `$results`? Also, this works, but the rows have to match amongst tables. Is it possible to have the names be in any order but still compare them?

Comment: You are correct on the `$result2` issue; I edited the code. As for ordering, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause to the SQL. However if the values can differ, you may need to order on another column, like ID or date created. Without knowing the table schema, it is hard to say.

Comment: I don't need to order them, I just need to see if any of the 8 in `tableOne` are equal to any of the 8 in `tableTwo`, and then if `tableTwo` doesn't contain the data in `tableOne`, then put a strike through the name(output) of `tableOne`. - but right now, it only puts a strike through the output of `tableOne` if it is in the corresponding row in `tableTwo`. ~ sorry that may sound confusing.

Comment: It sounds like you want a nested loop. The outer loop will be foreach table1 row. Inside, do a foreach table2 row, and compare. If you find a match, print it, else do the strikethrough.

Comment: yes that sounds right, but I'm not having luck on my end. Could you update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $sql="select * from tableone to left join tabletwo tw on to.weight=tw.weight ";
```

This query will return all the rows in tableone which matches and empty rows for the ones where the weight dont match.

So in your php code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      if(empty($row['weight'])){
        echo '<span class="strike">$row[weight]</span>';
      }
    }
```

This would work with any dynamic number of records in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping the values ($row[]) in one array($tableOne) and doing the same thing for table two ($tableTwo) and then perform your comparison in foreach()? (For the sake of simplicity, if you don't want any joins)