# Return Difference Between two MySQL Columns in Different Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to compare names in `tableOne` with names in `tableTwo`.  This code below does that, but it only compares the names in the corresponding rows. I would like to scan `tableTwo` to see if they match the names in `tableOne`, and if they do then add a strike to the names in `tableOne`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableOne LIMIT 0, 8");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableTwo");

$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $value1 = $row['names'];
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $value2 = $row2['names'];
    echo $i . " - "; 

    if ($value2 != $value1) {
        echo '<span class="strike">' . $value1 . '</span>';

    } else {
        echo $value2;
             $points = 7;
        echo '<span class="champ">' . '+' . $points . "</span>";
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543409/compare-mysql-data-with-another-table), but did not fully do what I needed to. I believe I need to do a nested loop but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: This is convoluted. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seems like [`array_diff`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) will do the job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to write a more complicated query and only loop once.

The query below joins together tableOne and tableTwo rows where the 'names' column match. If they don't match then the tableOne columns will exist but the tableTwo columns will all be null.

```
$sQuery = "SELECT tableOne.*, tableTwo.names as t2names 
FROM tableOne LEFT JOIN tableTwo USING (names) LIMIT 0, 8";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sQuery);

$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $value1 = $row['names'];
    echo $i . " - "; 

    if ($row['t2names']) {
        echo '<span class="strike">' . $value1 . '</span>';

    } else {
        echo $value1;
        $points = 7;
        echo '<span class="champ">' . '+' . $points . "</span>";
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

I rarely use mysql so the query may not work exactly

Comment: think you forgot a `"` in `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sQuery");` :)

Comment: Oops, I've fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On second read of your question I believe `array_intersect` is your better choice.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableOne LIMIT 0, 8");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableTwo");



    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array1[] = $row['names'];

    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $array2[] = $row['names'];

    }
    mysqli_free_result($result2);

    $intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

While I work with PDO myself, you basically get the independent arrays and then intersect them.

php: [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

When you have your array straightened out you can add your strikes.